# Create invoices in bulk using NetSuite RESTLET API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to create multiple invoices with a single POST request to the NetSuite REST API? I'm hoping there's a way to avoid sending thousands of individual requests.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your best option is use map/reduce  script    ,  here is a example:  https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RNnkZ-HK4qMJ:https://www.abaci-us.com/netsuite-map-reduce-script/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=mx

Comment: Please clarify if you're trying to use REST Web Services or a RESTlet SuiteScript type?  They are different.  Main difference is that REST Web Services has predefined record tables, operations, structured responses, and errors.  If using a RESTlet, I believe you'd have to write a custom way to handle the request and a custom response/output.

Comment: @Martha yes RESTLET SuiteScript with custom response output

Comment: @wozzarvl is there any way, I can pass JSON data string to getInputData function from restlet? the reason is because the data is coming from external portal.

Comment: @MuddassirUzair you can´t , in  getInputData  you get the records from a search, in this case if you have to send the info to the fullfilment  and then do the  Invoices   you have to make a loop from the external portal. Or  do the loop for fullment  and then  use the map/reduce to  make just the invoices

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here would be to look into `N/https` module in Suitescripts.

The idea here is simple. You will try to pass data using a UserEvent Script, the same data which now you are passing using Postman (or some testing application).

```
//Add additional code 
...
var response = https.post({
 url: 'https://www.testwebsite.com',
 body: myPostDataObj
});
...
//Add additional code
```

You can use a FOR LOOP later for iterating and creating as much records as you desire.

Hope this helped. Let me know in case of issues below.